# Selenium WebDriver - How to get id of the element when they have dynamic id?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a problem in this element (drop-down image), I have tried this elements but none of this works maybe because the two elements are the same and their id's are dynamic.
I tried getting the absolute Xpath and it works. (But this this is not a good idea)

Here's the element i have tried so far:

```
//div[@class='drop-image']
//div[contains(@class,'drop-image')]
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent div id is different.. You can use same..
Your 1st element parent id have sub-string as `BaseCurrencyCombo` while your 2nd element have `TargetCurrencyCombo`

1st element

```
//div[@id=ct100.....BaseCurrencyCombo]//div[@class='drop-image']
```

2nd element

```
//div[@id=ct100.....TargetCurrencyCombo]//div[@class='drop-image']
```

OR

```
//div[@class='drop-image'][1]
```

Please enter the correct/complete id in above both Xpath .. It's too long ;)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: i think the id of `BaseCurrencyCombo` and `TargetCurrencyCombo` are both dynamic isn't it?

Comment: oh.. if the both id's is dynamic is it anything similer you have found each time .. like may be all  those number change but BaseCurrentCombo will be always be same.. if this is the case then use contains for the id too

Comment: le me know if you find anything similar string after changing the dynamic values

Comment: Or you can try using //div[@class='drop-image'][1] .. here [1] means 1 element it found using xpath .. have a try .. use [2] after the xpath if you want 2nd element

Comment: `//div[@class='drop-image'][1]` works well and it is more cleaner. Thank you for the added knowledge sir!

Answer (score 1):

You said the div id's are dynamic ....however have u observed for the first part(USD) there is something called `BaseCurrencyCombo` under div `ID` whereas for the second part(EUR) it is `TargetCurrencyCombo`.
 So I don think so these two will get changed.
You can try these xpaths :

```
1>//div[contains(@id,'BaseCurrencyCombo')]//div[contains(@class,'drop-image')]
2>//div[contains(@id,'TargetCurrencyCombo')]//div[contains(@class,'drop-image')]
```